# Will the Hard Drive be ever used for temporary storage when running Ubuntu from a USB bootable drive?

Tags: boot, usb

I was just wondering where temporary files (like temporary internet files, cookies, etc...) will be saved when running Ubuntu from a USB dongle.

More generally I'm curious to know if on the Hard Drive will be ever left a track (apart from files explicitly saved by the user) of the activity done by running Ubuntu from a USB.

Comment: Is there an existing swap partition on the hard drive?

Comment: And if there is, are you telling the live USB to mount and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the host system has no existing swap partition, all temporary files should exist in RAM. However, if the system has an existing swap partition, files may *also* be written to the physical hard drive on the swap partiton.

To test this, you can run the following command to show any active swap partitions currently in use as well as the ammount of memory (if any) currently stored on the swap partition:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

To prevent this, you can use [zram](https://wiki.debian.org/ZRam) swap instead and turn swap off for the hard drive.

You can also use `bleachkit` to "clean" the swap partition but be carefull not to erase the wrong stuff.

Alternatively, you can turn off swap completely using the following command:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

and to periodically clear your ram, run the following command before ram gets full (it's probably safe to not have any important applications running when executing this command):

```
echo "3" | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK temporary files are written to a /tmp directory on the USB drive and application specific stuff usually gets put into your /home directory. Unless you explicit created a persistent partition on the drive then all of this gets removed when you reboot.

Based on the nature of your question it sounds like tails would be a good option for you to look into: https://tails.boum.org/

I think it does some extra stuff like scrubbing RAM.

Comment: it is important to note these known issues: first, for non-pae: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/#index21h2 next, on all systems video memory: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/#index22h2 and finally: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/#index26h2

Comment: @mchid Thanks for those links, really useful stuff!

Answer (score 0):

There should not be left a trace of temporary files on the hard drive. The cookies are typically stored in a dot directory for your browser in your home directory on the usb, for instance, `/home/user/.mozilla` in case of firefox. Unless you explicitly mount the hard drive and symlink that directory somewhere on the hard drive, you're safe. For extra security, you can just remove the hard drive completely, but that's in the realm of overkill

Comment: where will the files be stored if i am using a  read only CD?

Comment: I'd say in RAM. Though I cannot quite test it - I've no access to any cd right now. I did play with live usbs mostly